# How do i print a image in images tiles in Cocoa printing

Tags: cocoa, printing, macos-carbon, cgcontext

I had  Carbon code which prints image as tiles in . But now for 64 bit i want to change that into carbon. 
I have a CGContext which i need to print and which holds the new tile every time. 
I cant find a suitable workflow.

Any help would appreciated

Comment: So are you using Cocoa printing (NSPrintInfo, NSView, etc.), or Carbon printing (Core Printing)?

Comment: I am using Cocoa printing till now i have my code in Carbon. I am using NSPrintinfo and NSView